# Defining var + in Scala, is it useful?

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, identifier

Got into a discussion about the possible identifiers in Scala. It turns out you can define the variable `+`
Can this be useful? I can't seem to do anything with it:

```
felix@felix-UX32VD:~$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_21).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> var + = 42
+: Int = 42

scala> +
     | 
     | 
You typed two blank lines.  Starting a new command.

scala> List(+,+,+)
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       List(+,+,+)
             ^

scala> (+)
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       (+)
         ^

scala>
```

I understand that it is useful for function definitions, i.e. operator overloading, but it seems like Scala has support for primitive expressions and tries to parse it as such.

Is there any use to vars or vals with id + ?